# Excess pressure of soap bubble in different medium

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, bubbles

I have been wondering that why excess pressure of soap bubble remains

$${4S}/{R}$$

Even if it is in water or in air?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different compared to the air/water case?

Comment: @joseph h Actually in the text i am reading, this same derivation is done by the use of vector sum of forces on the greater circle of the sphere and in that derivation atmospheric pressure and is also considered. So obviously there will be problem when the soap bubble will be in water where the total pressure is atmospheric + pressure due to depth. So what are your thoughts on this

Comment: Using forces. For me it's quick and straightforward using work/energy. But whether you have atmospheric pressure or any pressure - under water, this does not change the definition. It's still the pressure difference between inside and outside. Make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. But if you can show me through force method in water it would be  on top of .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_i$ be pressure inside the bubble and $p_o$ be the pressure outside. Excess pressure is then
$$p = p_i - p_o$$ whether the bubble is in the air *or* in the water. That is the meaning of  excess pressure. Why the expression is given by $\frac{4S}{R}$ as above can be calculated as follows below.

---

The work done by this pressure is force$\times$displacement if we consider the radius of the bubble to be expanded (isothermally) by increment $dr$ : $$W=\underbrace{pA}_{force=pressure\times area}\times dr$$ so
$$W=p(4\pi r^2) dr\tag1$$ We also know that the increase in potential energy of expansion to $dr$ is $$dU=2F_T[4\pi(r+dr)^2-4\pi r^2]=16F_T\pi rdr\tag2$$ which is surface tension$\times$change in surface area$^1$.

Since work done is equal to the change in potential energy, we can equate (1) and (2) and then integrate over $r$, to give a final expression for pressure excess, $$p=\frac{4F_T}{R}$$

$^1$Note the factor of two in the front since there are two surfaces (inner surface and outer surface) of the bubble which is why in the final expression you have a factor of 4.

Comment: What do you mean by two sides of the bubble?

Comment: The inner  surface and outer surface.